# Multiplatform C BLE dependency issue

Tags: c, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, clion, bluez

I am building an app using `bluez` in C.

I am using CLion as my dev environment with two targets - A raspberry Pi 4B and my Linux machine.

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(bluetooth_client C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-lbluetooth")
add_executable(bluetooth_client main.c)
```

When I run this targeting the raspberry pi (aka remote host), it works fine. When I run it targeting the local host (Linux on intel) it shows this build message:
[image]

I tried to verify if I have the exact libraries installed. When I edit code while targeting the Linux dev it correctly sees all the Bluetooth libraries (bluetooth/hci/hci_lib).

The code I run is from Edison-Playground

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Post the text as text in your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-lbluetooth")` is putting the library before the executable, which results in an invalid order and linker doesn't find your symbol.

Do not use `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` directly at all, forget it exists - use various `add_*` facilities instead, like `add_compile_options`, `add_link_options`. Use `target_link_libraries(bluetooth_client PRIVATE bluetooth)` for linking.

Comment: I never knew this. This worked. Could you recommend some resources where I could learn about features like the one described above? Thank you!

Comment: Most of my knowledge I got from browsing [cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/). There [are tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+introduction) like [this one](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/) and they are good, but there is this problem that it's hard to explain everything. ;) The problem with cmake, you basically "discover" best practices and features from random places, mostly because it's still very dynamically developed thing